# Looking for example Terraform projects to set up AWS infra containing VPCs, SGs, EC2s, RDS etc

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am looking for example terraform projects to refer when building infra for my project. It deals with Customer data and needs to secure to outside traffic, and don't have resources to hire a DevOps/SecOps. So if you have come across any terraform templates or projects that spin up VPC,SecurityGroups, EC2s, RDS instances and networking between them, it would be helpful. Currently these are all built individually and glued together manually, but I would like to set this up as a project. Also let me know what I am trying to do possible. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow isn't really designed for recommending resources for you to look at. Stack Overflow works best when you have a specific question about some code you have written that isn't behaving how you want. If you post that code and say why it doesn't do what you want (ie it errors with this error message) then people are able to more directly help here.

Comment: You can use the `almost-official Terraform modules for AWS` [here](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules)

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I was hoping that my question will get enough eyes if posted here. Will try in other forums too.

Comment: @Stargazer Thank you, will take a look.